# Send packet python

Tags: python, packet

How to do it in python?
Some like this.

```
PacketBuffer[0] := $00;
PacketBuffer[1] := $12;
PacketBuffer[2] := $12;
'SendPacket(ProcessID, @PacketBuffer, TRUE, FALSE);'
```

Comment: I dont think you can send packets to a process ... only a server or file

Comment: It's not very clear what you want `SendPacket` to do.

Comment: What language is your code sample in?

Comment: sample delphi with packet.dll

Comment: yes i know packets send to server but from processid

Answer (score 0):

Use the socket module:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((your_host, your_port))
msg_to_send = 'whatever'
num_sent = 0
while num_sent < len(msg_to_send):
    sent = s.send(msg_to_send[num_sent:])
    if sent == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
    num_sent += sent
```